# Load comments in post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Let's say I have this structure in my Firebase DB

[image]

**Edited:
my JSON structure looks like this:**

```
{
  ad-comments:{
    48a047b7-28a2-4037-925c-2a809b8d4445:{
      -K4iGKXbniQZUi4r1SW7:{
         Comment:""
         Email:""
         Date:""
         Submitter:""
         ID:""
      }
      -K4hxcKuuxcwuhScPR_v:{...}    
    }
    eeb082e5-59ed-4c3b-8fcd-5af24a2bcada:{...}    
  }
  users:{
    48a047b7-28a2-4037-925c-2a809b8d4445:{
      text:""
      name:""
      email:""
      desc:""
      phone:""
    }
    444198db-1052-4d8d-a1cd-c7e613fbe7c9:{...}  
  }
}
```

In the controller Im retrieving the users (each user has a property post) to display them on the view using $firebaseArray and ng-repeat like this:

```
var ref = new Firebase ("https://url.firebaseio.com/users");
$scope.posts = $firebaseArray("ref");
```

Now in the view I simply use a ng-repeat to iterate through them

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">

  <div>{{post.name}}</div>
  <div>{{post.text}}</div>

  <div>Comments:<div>
     <div><input type="text" ng-model="comment"></div>
     <div><button ng-click="addComment(post, comment)">Add</button></div>
</div>
```

So now, the question is how can I make a query to request all the comments for each post when they are in different nodes, I store them by ID but still can't figure out how to do it.

Before I was storing the comments inside of each user and it was possible to show the comments on each post, but I was having problems with the security rules because I had specified that a user can only modify its own content and not the others, and leaving the comments inside users didnt allow to others to comments, so I had to change and put the comments in a different node.

Comment: Can you provide your JSON data structure in code? Just a few samples under each location should help. It looks like you're really close :)

Comment: @DavidEast sorry, dont think I understood what you need, can you explain a little more? thanks :)

Comment: You uploaded in image of your data, but it only provides the key. If I saw the actual JSON dump (just a sample not the whole thing) it would be easy to answer.

Comment: Ah ok, got it, I edited my question hope is what you need @DavidEast

Comment: What's the value of `post`? And what's the difference between `ad-comments`, and `posts`? Are posts a join of data between `users` and `ad-comments1?

Comment: sorry it was "text" and you can read in the ng-repeat loop as {{post.text}} it could be anything, whatever a user want to post as string.

Comment: Where is the post stored in the Firebase database?

Comment: @DavidEast ad-comments is the node where the comments of a post should be stored with the ID of the post. It's a little confusing but take a user as each post (the user in this case) instead. Each user has a unique post and in the JSON above is named as "text". hope it's understandable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You're keeping your data flat, which is awesome!**

You're also using a shared key between the two locations, which means you're 90% of the way there.

There are multiple ways of handling this situation, but [using `.$extend()` in AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-creating-angularfire-services) provides an elegant solution.

The code examples below use the [Angular Styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide), so don’t worry if the code looks unfamiliar to you.

[Here's the full demo on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/toqanoyizi/edit?html,js,output), and below are the steps for creating it.

We want to load the comments **for every user**. We'll first create a factory that gets the `ad-comments` by `uid`:

```
function UserCommentsArray($firebaseArray, rootRef) {
  return function UserCommentsArray(uid) {
    var userCommentsRef = rootRef.child('ad-comments').child(uid);
    return $firebaseArray(userCommentsRef);
  };
}
```

Now we'll use `$firebaseArray.$extend()` to create a custom synchronized array.

```
function UsersArray($firebaseArray, rootRef, userCommentsArray) {
    return $firebaseArray.$extend({
      $$added: function(snap) {
        var user = snap.val();
        user.$id = snap.key();
        user.comments = userCommentsArray(snap.key());
        return user;
    }
  });
}
```

Every time an item is added to the array, we’ll create a user object and tack on the comments from the `userCommentsArray`.

Now in our controller code, we can simply inject the `usersArray` and bind to the page.

```
function MyCtrl($scope, rootRef, usersArray) {
  var usersRef = rootRef.child('users');
  $scope.users = usersArray(usersRef);
}
```

Displaying this data on the page requires a change to the template:

```
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="user in users">

      <div>{{user.name}}</div>

      <ul ng-repeat="comment in user.comments">
        <li>{{ comment.text }}</li>
      </ul>

      <div>Comments:</div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="newComment">
      </div>

      <div>
        <button 
          ng-click="addComment(user, newComment)">Add
        </button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Adding comments underneath a user is done by finding the user and then calling `$add()` on the comments array.

```
function MyCtrl($scope, rootRef, usersArray) {
  var usersRef = rootRef.child('users');
  $scope.users = usersArray(usersRef);
  $scope.addComment = function (user, newComment) {
    var userRecord = $scope.users.$getRecord(user.$id);
    userRecord.comments.$add({ text: newComment });
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked, finally I can see it working...yeahhh!!! I owe you some beers ;)

Comment: Last question...how could I add a limitToFirst(n) when looping through the users?

Comment: Open another question. Will be easier to answer in that format.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Firebase expert but I think you should think how to model the connection between a post and its comments.
I can think of two ways:

1. Post entity will have an additional field:

   List commentIds
2. Comment entity will hold the Id of the post

I recommend the first approach since usually we would like the owner entity (in this case the Post entity) to hold its children (Comment)

Now when you are retrieving a Post, make sure you retrieve all its comments by using the comments Ids.

Comment: The Firebase Database is a NoSQL JSON datastore. There's no native joins or relationships. There's an easier technique than joining with Firebase. I think I know what the issue is, but I'll need to see the structure of the data.